# Why is my method not being detected in the main method?

Tags: java, class, methods, subclass

I'm just testing out some inheritance, but it seems that my methods are not being called, or even seen by the main method. It compiles, but just says there is are no methods detected in the file. What's wrong with my code?

```
public class monkey
{
    public void main(String[] args){
          Fruit jeff = new Fruit("ree");
          Fruit mike = new Apple("ree");

          jeff.talk();
          mike.talk();
    }

class Fruit 
{ 
    String sound;
    public Fruit(String s) { 
      sound = s;
    } 

    public void talk(){
      System.out.print(sound);
    }
} 

class Apple extends Fruit 
{ 
   public Apple(String s){
      super(s);
   }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: How are you trying to run the java program through IDE or console ?

Comment: You need to make your `main` method static

Comment: Your main methods singnature is wrong. It should be like `public static void main(String[] args){}`

Comment: error message is `Error: Main method is not static in class monkey, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)`. Also your classes are defined inside monkey. Move them outside if you want to fix the next error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- put static in main method signature.
- create static inner classes because you want to access those classes in static main method.

Correct Code:

```
public class monkey {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit jeff = new Fruit("ree");
        Fruit mike = new Apple("ree");

        jeff.talk();
        mike.talk();
    }

    static class  Fruit {
        String sound;

        public Fruit(String s) {
            sound = s;
        }

        public void talk() {
            System.out.print(sound);
        }
    }

    static class Apple extends Fruit {
        public Apple(String s) {
            super(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't agree that the Fruit and Apple classes need to be static inner classes. You can put them in other files or simply not make them public classes. The fact they are accessed in a static method does not mean they themselves have to be static classes.